# Will my installed archlinux run on another machine by replacing the hard drive?

Tags: boot, system-installation, hardware

Today I installed archlinux on my hard drive-A on my computer-A. Now I want my computer B run archlinux. Can I simply replace the hard drive B of computer-B with hard drive-A?

Note that I just installed the minimum package of arch, and the desktop is just lxde and lxdm, very small.

However, computer A and B are from different vendors and their ram is different, one is ddr2 and the other is ddr3... cpu is different, one is i5 the other is T2400, both support 64bit.

Comment: The kernel *should* just detect and deal with the changes. I have done this in the past but not with Arch so I'm not sure enough to post an answer.

Comment: @terdon This means it is very likely..

Comment: Yes. I would expect it to work. Why don't you just try and then post an answer letting us know how it went? :P

Comment: @terdon Do you think there is any different of replacement or just link drive-A via usb and boot from there?

Comment: @terdon This is easier...

Comment: I deleted your answer since it wasn't really answering the question. It should be edited into your question instead. If you need instructions on *how* to do this (as opposed to what you are currently asking for: confirmation of whether it is possible or not), then you'll also need to [edit] your question and tell us more about your system. Is it BIOS or EFI? Are you using an external bootloader? Which one? Where is it installed? Is it installed in the drive you want to move? How many partitions does the drive have? You can't just use it as an external USB bootable drive, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that when I replace drive-B on computer-B with drive-A, the archlinux boots well. The software also works well, although there are huge differences on the hardware of two computers.